# VIM listchars except nerdtree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I wrote the following in my .vimrc to highlight the spaces

```
set list
set lischars=space:.
```

But it highlights all spaces in all buffers. I want to highlight spaces for all buffers except NerdTree buffer. Is it possible? Im try to do this

```
autocmd bufenter * if $ft != nerdtree | set list
```

But of course after entering any buffer spaces in NerdTree highlights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
......
set list
set lischars=space:.
.....
....
```

Then this line would do:

```
autocmd FileType nerdtree setlocal nolist
```